# c++ function that accepts ostringstream like arguments?

Tags: c++, string, function, stream, arguments

Is there a way in C++ to define a function so that I could do things like this:

```
foo( "Error on line " << iLineNumber );
foo( "name " << strName << " is Invalid" );
```

as it is now, I'm having to declare an ostringstream object before I call the foo function like this:

```
std::ostringstream strStream1;
ostringstream1 << "Error on line " << iLineNumber;
foo( ostringstream1 );

std::ostringstream strStream2;
ostringstream2 << "name " << strName << " is Invalid";
foo( ostringstream2 );
```

Comment: About to learn, you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is not able to deduce that you want your expression to be converted to `std::ostringstream`. You can get around this by explicitly providing one to the arguments, which you can do inline with the function :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void foo(std::ostringstream osstr)
{
    // Use the stream
}

int main()
{
    const int iLineNumber = 10;
    const std::string strName = "file.cpp";

    foo( std::ostringstream{} << "Error on line " << iLineNumber );
    foo( std::ostringstream{} << "name " << strName << " is Invalid" );
}
```

However, I recommend using a parameter pack and fold expression instead to forward the arguments :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

// Parameter, variable number of arguments of various types
template<class ... T>
void foo(T&& ... args)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    // Fold expression, for each argument in args, add it to the stream
    (stream << ... << std::forward<T>(args));

    // Use the stream
}

int main()
{
    const int iLineNumber = 10;
    const std::string strName = "file.cpp";

    foo( "Error on line ", iLineNumber );
    foo( "name ", strName, " is Invalid" );
}
```

Comment: C++ streams can't be copied, so `void foo(std::ostringstream osstr)` will not work, it would need to be `void foo(const std::ostringstream &osstr)` instead, or better `void foo(std::ostringstream &&osstr)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau std::ostringstream is move constructible, and the argument is always an rvalue reference (see [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/output.streams#ostream.rvalue)) so it does works out as it is now. But you are right though that using a reference parameter would be better and make the function more general.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue is that the string and number below

```
oss << "String " << number;
```

are not "ostringstream arguments". They're each parameters to different overloads of the `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, T)` family. The whole statement expands to

```
operator<<(operator<<(oss, "String "), number);
```

and the tokens `"String " << number` are never evaluated as an expression. There is no suitable overload of `operator<<`, and even if there were, there's no reason to expect it would create the `ostringstream` you want.

---

There are three ways to do roughly what you want, and François has already shown two:

1. Manually create an anonymous `ostringstream`

   Not beautiful, no extra work now, but extra work at every call site
2. Make your function a variadic template (or write a variadic wrapper) to format the arguments into an `ostringstream` for you

   Easy to implement, but doesn't use the `<<` syntax you seem so keen on
3. Write a streaming proxy sentinel type, which would look like this at the call site:

   ```
    foo() << "Error on line " << iLineNumber;
   ```

   This is a load of effort just to preserve the syntactic style, but might occasionally be justified.

   The object would contain an `ostringstream` and have a templated `operator<<` allowing it to format any type.

   I called it a "sentinel" because it also needs to call the original `foo()` function with that formatted string, from its destructor.

   This is actually a pretty bad idea if the inner `foo()` function might throw.

Answer (score 0):

@Useless has give a few possibilities. I'll throw one more into the mix to see if you find it interesting.

Right now, your code that works has something like:

```cpp
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << "whatever";
foo(buffer);
```

It's fairly easy to turn that around, so to speak, to get something along these lines:

```cpp
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << "whatever" << exec(foo);
```

...and have that `exec` invoke `foo` with the current contents of the stringstream:

```cpp
class exec {
    void (*func)(std::string const &);
public:
    exec(void (*func)(std::string const &)) : func(func) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, exec const &e) { 
        std::ostringstream &oss = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream &>(os);
        e.func(oss.str());
        return os;
    }
};
```

Here's a trivial (but complete) working example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class exec {
    void (*func)(std::string const &);
public:
    exec(void (*func)(std::string const &)) : func(func) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, exec const &e) { 
        std::ostringstream &oss = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream &>(os);
        e.func(oss.str());
        return os;
    }
};

void foo(std::string const &s) {
  std::cout << s;
}

int main() {
  std::ostringstream os;

  os << "This is some stuff: " << 1 << " " << 3.14 << exec(foo);
}
```

...which produces pretty much what you'd expect:

```
This is some stuff: 1 3.14
```